# What is the use case for an anonymous union type

Tags: c++, c

A saw a question with the following code :

```
union
{
     float dollars;
     int yens;
}price;
```

`price` is a variable whose type does not have a name.
What is such an unnamed type useful for? Lambda expressions?
Is this valid in both C and C++?

Comment: This is not duplicate at all, where is the typedef as in the link you provided ?

Comment: Something else (some other data) would tell which union member to use. And you really should show more code, and choose between C and C++ (which are different languages). So ask a new question or strongly edit this one.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch The core of the question is not "what is a union for?" but "why does this union type not have a name, and why?"

Comment: that is what I meant, question is updated ;-) thanks angew.

Comment: @PhilipStuyck: you still need to improve your question (so edit it please again) to show much more code and choose between C and C++.

Comment: How can I show more code as I don't know why this unnamed type is useful for, I am basically asking for an example.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch I suspect the answer to this question is exactly the same in C or C++.

Comment: For C++, a useful example is [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26522663/841108)

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch No, I don't think that's an example. This is a *named* union of unnamed type. So it cannot be used as the "trailing variadic member."

Comment: No, my example is exactly an *unamed* `union`. A *named* union would be `union unionname`

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch Right, sorry. I meant a "named object of unnamed union type." Which still disqualifies it as the trailing variant.

Comment: I believe your "trailing variant" is non-standard terminology, and suggests that you think *wrongly* about unions. So pick a book on [C++ programming](http://www.stroustrup.com/Programming/), and read it more.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch OK, it's a part of the language I use quite rarely. Still, C++11 9.5/5+7 prevent an "anonymous union" from having a named instance. The "trailing variant" is indeed non-standard, I didn't mean it as a term; the standard term is "union-like class" and "variant members," 9.5/8

Comment: So I did. I was reluctant to remove it in the first place but some reactions were rather heavy.

Comment: @PhilipStuyck Agree ... :) and I don't understand downvote on such sensible questions

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The fact that the type does not have a name has very little effect on the use of the `price` variable. All it means is that you cannot (easily) create another object of this type.

This construct makes the most sense if `price` is a local variable inside a function. If you only ever want one object of this type, you don't need to name the type, so why bother. It doesn't differ at all from:

```
union SomeNameIPromiseNotToUseAnywhereAndWhichDoesntConflictWithAnything
{
  float dollars;
  int yens;
} price;
```

Notice that in C++11 and beyond, you *can* actually create another object:

```
decltype(price) anotherPrice;
```

Answer (score 2):

In C++, it is valid. The code defines a local variable called price, which can either store an integer value in `yens` or a float value in `dollars`.

Without seeing how it is used, I can only conclude that the variable is a local/temporary variable (and probably, in a function that attempts to do too much).

Example:

```
union
{
     float dollars;
     int yens;
} price;

if(currency != "USD")
    price.yens = ConvertToYEN(fullPrice);
else
    price.dollars = GetUpdatedPriceInUSD(abc, currency);

if(currency == "YEN")
   std::cout << "Using price in yens: " << price.yens << "\n";
```

Answer (score 1):

In C according to this link

https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Unnamed-Fields.html#Unnamed-Fields

You can just access the the member of the union like `price.dollars` and `price.yens` because `price` is already an variable of type union and there is no need to create a new object of same type.

```
union
{
     float dollars;
     int yens;
}price;

int main(void) {
    price.dollars = 90.5;
    printf("%f\n",price.dollars);
    price.yens = 20;
    printf("%d\n",price.yens);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I have used unions in the past as mechanisms for handling storage formats and translating between them.

For example, it could be that the program includes code for storing amounts in a a file in float format and that the storage function accepts/returns a float. Later,  it is discovered we need to use an integer, so we simply use the union so access the data in the format we know it to be. For example:

```
price.dollars = load_from_file();
if (yen_flag)
    // use price.yen
else
    // use price.dollars
```

It is also commonly used for implementation independent storage of ints.

```
union {
    int int_val;
    char as_bytes[4];
} int_store;
```

Sorry if there are any syntax errors, it's been a while ...

Answer (score 0):

I saw code like this in alot of mathematical libraries for 2D/3D calculation:

```
struct Matrix3x3
{
    union
    {
        struct
        {
            float m00 , m01 , m02;
            float m10 , m11 , m12;
            float m20 , m21 , m22;
        };

        float m[ 3 ][ 3 ];
    };
};
```

[see also this Q](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2253878/why-does-c-disallow-anonymous-structs-and-unions)

---

iirc, I read somewhere that using such methods leads to violating the *strict aliasing rule*

Answer (score 0):

```
struct FooBar
{
    union
    {
        Foo foo;
        char dummy[128];
    };
    Bar bar;
};
```

I've seen people use nameless unions to control the offset of `struct` members.

There's no trivial way to align a `struct` member to a certain boundary, but there are ways to align the beginning of the `struct` to arbitrary boundaries, then pad the member to the next boundary.